# Can we substitute 'as to' with 'for'?

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

This question came to me after reading someone's comment somewhere. She wrote:

> She did not have a clue **as to** how to relate to the teenagers.

I've seen people here commonly use the phrase **as to** when explaining their answers. I haven't realized it's an idiom [used when you are referring to something] until I looked-up. I've been using 'for' before this. So, before I knew I could use this (I hadn't known the usage of this idiom), perhaps, I would write:

> She did not have a clue **for** how to relate to the teenagers.

The reason is both **as to** and **for** have the same translation in my native language. Does using **for** still make sense?

Comment: "not have a clue ... how to" can be used with "as to", "about" or nothing. "For" is incorrect.

Comment: Leaving out "as to" altogether giving "She did not have a clue how to relate to teenagers" is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasal preposition "as to" is widely used and has a long history in English, but some people (including me) frown upon it. It sounds somewhat awkward to me, and when editing others' writing, I often recommend changing it. (I'm not saying that it's technically wrong, only that I think that other prepositions sound better.) In your sentence, "for" would be unusual; I would use "about".